# Only one letter of string is being passed to Django views function from template

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

HTML form:

```
<form id="save_form" method="post" action="{% url 'project_save' usernames=username project_name='lion' %}">
```

Notice the arg 'project_name's value is 'lion'

views.py:

```
def projectz_save(request, usernames, project_name):
    template = loader.get_template('project_view/index.html')
    context = RequestContext(request, {"username": usernames, "project": project_name})
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context))
```

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
url(r'^(?P<usernames>\w+)(?P<project_name>\w+)save$', views.projectz_save, name='project_save'),
)
```

What happens is that only the 'n' in 'lion' is being passed as an argument. When I re-render the page, the template variable "project" now has the value 'n' instead of 'lion.' Any idea why this is happening?

It happens if I use a variable instead of a string (which is obviously the ultimate goal), but even simplified down to a simple string it's still happening.

Comment: edited in in there..thanks for taking a look

Comment: why do you have `save` at the end of the url pattern?

Comment: It used to be this: url(save$', views.projectz_save, name='project_save')

But then I needed to add 2 arguments to the projectz_save function, so I passed them with regex captures

Comment: I got rid of the "save" part in the urls.py and still have the same problem. I'm still new to Django so my understanding of the interaction between url tag from the template and the urls.py is somewhat limited

Comment: I know that the function is running though, because it does re-render fine, except that only the last character of the string is present. If i change it from "lion" to "fish", it would display an "h" instead of a "n."

Comment: this is so wierd.. your pattern matching is fine. Just try `{% url 'project_save' username 'lion' %}`

Comment: would it have anything to do with the fact that the html page that is loaded is very large and full of javascript and jquery?

Comment: I tried your suggestion...still get the same problem. so weird.

Comment: i dont think so. A context variable has to be called properly no matter how big the file is

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that while the template is correctly constructing the URL, your urls.py regexp is too greedy.

Specifically, you have no divider between your usernames named group and your project name named group:

```
r'^(?P<usernames>\w+)(?P<project_name>\w+)save$'
```

Given any sequence of word characters, all but the last will be matched by the `\w+` in the usernames group.  The last will be matched by the project_name group, because + requires at least one character.  So if username in the template is 'johndoe', the `url` tag will construct the URL:

```
johndoelionsave
```

The regexp will then match `johndoelio` as the usernames group, since all of those are matched by `\w+`, `n` as the project_name group, since it's matched by `\w+`, and then the fixed `save` and end-of-string parts.

Your best fix will be to break up the URL pattern so that the parsing is unambiguous.  I suggest:

```
r'^(?P<usernames>\w+)/(?P<project_name>\w+)/save$'
```

In which case the template tag will produce:

```
johndoe/lion/save
```

and the regexp will parse out the details you want.